# Is it possible to write any c# or server side code in SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: development, javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to render some code dynamically so is it possible to write any C# code in SharePoint hosted app environment?
And if not, then what are some alternative approach to achieve such goal?

Answer (score 6):

A *SharePoint-hosted App* (aka *SharePoint-hosted Add-in*) cannot embed C# code. It's made of JavaScript only code.
The other kind of Apps (*Provider-hosted App*) may use C# code, but that code will run on a third-party server (and could use C# client API for SharePoint, as well as the identity of the initial user, if the App is used in Office 365 and thus leverages oAuth mechanisms).

Comment: So is there is any alternate possible solution?

Comment: No. use provider hosted app and  write  c# code without SERVER OBJECT MODEL. Another approach is  abandon the app model , go with traditional on-premises solution with fully leveraging SSOM.